# how to add a a terms and conditions page to the footer in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently am working on a site in wordpress and am trying to add a t and cs page but I diont want it to show in the nav, I would like it to only be in the footer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Open up the footer.php for your theme (`/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/footer.php`), scroll down to the part of the file that echoes out the footer links, and you can append it there. (if you don't have a `footer.php`, try looking near the bottom of `page.php`)

Note that this is a dirty quick hack, there's probably a more semantic way to get this done.

Comment: how would i do this as i made the footer from scratch

Comment: Then just append the links to your custom made footer wherever it is

Answer (score 0):

Open footer.php in your theme.

add this line and change match to your TOS page url

```
<a href="url/to/term-and-condition.html">TOS</a>
```